# SQLite database locked while bundled with advanced installer

Tags: java, sqlite

I have created a Java swing application with SQLite database using netbeans ide. When I run the application using application jar file it works fine, but when I create an exe using advanced installer, the db file getting locked in windows 7 for any changes(insert, update). What to do?

Comment: do you install the DB with the setup package generated by Advanced Installer, if so, in which folder? does that folder has write/read permissions?

Comment: Yes. I have tried in C:\Program Files\.. and also in other drive but don't success. I have checked the properties of the db file and it has no write permission to user level. Then I have tried to run my exe as administrator and now it succeed. But how can I give write permission to user level.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are placing the DB in a location that requires admin privileges to write. I suggest trying to place it in ProgramData folder, where Microsoft also recommends, and design your application to look for the DB there. The folder "Common Application Data" from Advanced Installer is the one pointing to the system folder "ProgramData".